# How to hide and show WKInterfaceGroup programmatically with animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, caanimation, watchkit

The solution in this question* uses setHidden to hide and unhide a WKInterfaceGroup:

```
    atypeofGroup.setHidden(true)
    atypeofGroup.setHidden(false)
```

But the problem is, the group will appear and disappear abruptly, it doesn't look professional. Can someone guide me please? Not sure whether it is related to this:

```
    atypeofGroup.animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!)
```

*[hide and show WKInterfaceGroup programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448043/hide-and-show-wkinterfacegroup-programmatically/28449386#28449386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, but it just isn't possible to animate a change between two groups with the current implementation of `WatchKit`. I definitely wish it was as well.

The only options you have are to switch interface controllers entirely through the `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` or to show/hide a couple of groups using the approach you listed first. Here's a small example of how you could switch from a `SimpleInterfaceController` to a `FirstInterfaceController` and `SecondInterfaceController` in a page set.

```
class SimpleInterfaceController : WKInterfaceController {
    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        let names = ["FirstInterfaceIdentifier", "SecondInterfaceIdentifier"]
        WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(names, contexts: nil)
    }
}
```

I am not sure where you found the following code snippet, but it is certainly not part of the public APIs on [WKInterfaceGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceGroup_class/index.html).

```
atypeofGroup.animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!)
```

While I understand none of these answers are ideal, they are all we have access to at the moment. If you have the time, I'd suggest filing a feature request on Apple's [bug reporting system](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Hi cnoon, thanks for your reply. Without the ability to do something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060070/how-to-unhide-view-with-animations for watchkit is certainly giving me a headache. Can you please provide an example on how to use reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:? What's the use of  atypeofGroup.animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!) btw?

Comment: Hi user, I edited my answer to address both your follow-up questions in your comment. Hopefully that helps make things a bit more clear.

Comment: Hi @VanDuTran which app are you referring to? Maybe they are using sequence of images to animate it smoothly...